# Rust: Passing async function pointers

Tags: rust

Let's say we have this code:

```rust
fn inc(src: u32) -> u32 {
    src + 1
}

fn inc2(src: u32) -> u32 {
    src + 2
}

type Incrementer = fn(u32) -> u32;
fn increment_printer(inc: Incrementer) {
    println!("{}", inc(1));
}

fn main() {
    increment_printer(inc);
    increment_printer(inc2);
}
```

Two functions with the same signature and a 3rd one that accepts pointers for them. Running this code results in 2\n3 being printed.

But something similar won't compile:

```rust
use core::future::Future;

async fn inc(src: u32) -> u32 {
    src + 1
}

async fn inc2(src: u32) -> u32 {
    src + 2
}

type Incrementer = fn(u32) -> dyn Future<Output = u32>;
async fn increment_printer(inc: Incrementer) {
    println!("{}", inc(1).await);
}

fn main() {
    async {
        increment_printer(inc).await;
        increment_printer(inc2).await;
    }
}
```

```
18 |         increment_printer(inc).await;
   |                           ^^^ expected trait object `dyn Future`, found opaque type
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `fn(_) -> (dyn Future<Output = u32> + 'static)`
                 found fn item `fn(_) -> impl Future {inc}`
```

I know that each async function has its own type, as mentioned in the error. Is it possible to force the compiler to forget about the concrete type and treat them as similar types?

Maybe it's possible to force an async function to return a `Box<Future<Output=u32>>`?

I don't want to give up async functions for convenience. Also I don't want to require calling Box::pin() before passing the async function pointer to the function.

It would be interesting to know if there are more options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Maybe it's possible to force an async function to return a Box<Future<Output=u32>>?

Not really, but it's possible to wrap the function into a closure that calls the function and returns a boxed future. Of course, the closure itself needs to be boxed so functions like `increment_printer` can receive it, but both boxings can be encapsulated in a utility function. For example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d2156fdac1265b0c2e62bd31f9c356e6)):

```
use core::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;

async fn inc(src: u32) -> u32 {
    src + 1
}

async fn inc2(src: u32) -> u32 {
    src + 2
}

type Incrementer = Box<dyn FnOnce(u32) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = u32>>>>;

fn force_boxed<T>(f: fn(u32) -> T) -> Incrementer
where
    T: Future<Output = u32> + 'static,
{
    Box::new(move |n| Box::pin(f(n)))
}

async fn increment_printer(inc: Incrementer) {
    println!("{}", inc(1).await);
}

fn main() {
    async {
        increment_printer(force_boxed(inc)).await;
        increment_printer(force_boxed(inc2)).await;
    };
}
```

If you can afford to make functions like `increment_printer` generic, then you can get rid of the outer box ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8435f34f94963c32a9c990be950cd27d)):

```
// emulate trait alias
trait Incrementer: FnOnce(u32) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = u32>>> {}
impl<T> Incrementer for T
    where T: FnOnce(u32) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = u32>>>
{
}

fn force_boxed<T>(f: fn(u32) -> T) -> impl Incrementer
where
    T: Future<Output = u32> + 'static,
{
    move |n| Box::pin(f(n)) as _
}

async fn increment_printer(inc: impl Incrementer) {
    println!("{}", inc(1).await);
}
```

> I don't want to give up async functions for convenience. Also I don't want to require calling `Box::pin()` before passing the async function pointer to the function.

You need to call `Box::pin()` *somewhere* - with the above the call is at least confined to one place, and you get an `Incrementer` type, of sorts, as the receiver of async functions passed through `force_boxed()`.

Comment: It works, and the API is not that bad. Still would've been ideal to not have to do the FnOnce dance. That being said, thank you, you saved me a fair amount of time.

Comment: @Dude Glad it helped - I've now edited the answer to simplify the signature of `force_boxed()` (it can accept a function, not an `FnOnce` itself), and to provide an alternative solution that doesn't require the closure to be boxed, at the cost of requiring functions like `increment_printer` to be generic.

Comment: [Here's an idea based on this answer](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8520a3bd55e7adeb5ebe2dbb293bef4a) that allows using a function pointer for `Incrementer`, so you don't need generics (but you *do* need a macro to wrap the `async fn` on demand).

Comment: @trentcl Nice! You might want to post it as an answer.

Comment: Done. Also, congrats on 100k rep!

Comment: May I ask what if the function pointer takes references as parameters intead of `u32`? Is it still possible to use the same approach?

Comment: This should be required reading for async developers!!! I learned so much using this technique for my own needs, and so much about async/await in Rust became crystal clear after sorting out the wrinkles my own use-case introduced to the overall approach!

A HUGE thank you @user4815162342 !!!

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe it's possible to force an async function to return a `Box<Future<Output=u32>>`?

You can do so by wrapping it in an ordinary (non-`async`) function:

```
fn boxed_inc(src: u32) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = u32>>> {
    Box::pin(inc(src))
}
// Use like:
increment_printer(boxed_inc).await;
```

However, that would quickly get tedious if you had to write `boxed_inc`, `boxed_inc2`, etc. for all the `async` functions that you needed to wrap. Here's a macro that wraps it on demand:

```
macro_rules! force_boxed {
    ($inc:expr) => {{
        // I think the error message referred to here is spurious, but why take a chance?
        fn rustc_complains_if_this_name_conflicts_with_the_environment_even_though_its_probably_fine(src: u32) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = u32>>> {
            Box::pin($inc(src))
        }
        rustc_complains_if_this_name_conflicts_with_the_environment_even_though_its_probably_fine
    }}
}
// Use like:
increment_printer(force_boxed!(inc)).await;
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8435f34f94963c32a9c990be950cd27d)

This is similar to and inspired by the `force_boxed` function in [user4815162342's answer](/a/66769658/3650362), but in this case it has to be a macro in order to coerce the result to a function pointer instead of merely a closure.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same thing, using the trait system:

```
#[async_trait]
trait Incrementor {
    async fn increment(&self, src: u32) -> u32;
}
```

and then implement the different incrementors as you wish.

```
#[async_trait]
impl Incrementor for Inc1 {
    async fn increment(&self, src: u32) -> u32 {
        src + 1
    }
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct Inc2;

#[async_trait]
impl Incrementor for Inc2 {
    async fn increment(&self, src: u32) -> u32 {
        src + 2
    }
}
```

This has the benefit of using static dispatch, if you control the objects invocation from the start, if not, it will still work with trait objects.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=42e804f030f101d63059091a23efbfa0)